# How to group this dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, data-manipulation

I have this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

stripline = "----------------------------"

rawData = {
    'order number': ['11xa', '11xa', '11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working area': ['LLA', 'LLE', 'LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': [1, 6, 13, 35, 24]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
print("original data:")
print(df.head())

print(stripline)

rawData2 = {
    'order number': ['11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working area': ['LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': [20, 35, 24]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rawData2)

print("expected result:")
print("group after order number, sum all times to that order and choose working field with the biggest time")
print(df2.head())
```

How can I manipulate my dataframe df to get the df2?

I want to sum up all values in the time column that correspond to an order number. I want to use the working field with the highest time and especially I want to keep the rest of the data. The new data frame has three orders, the old one five.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

rawData = {
    'order_number': ['11xa', '11xa', '11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working_area': ['LLA', 'LLE', 'LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': ['1', '6', '13', '35', '24']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(int) 
df = df.groupby('order_number', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.assign(sum=g.time.sum()))
df.groupby('order_number', ascending=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time').head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

gives you

```
  order_number working_area  time  sum
0         11xa          LLA     1   20
1         21xb          MLA    35   35
2         31xc          MLE    24   24
```

Comment: No, this gives a dataframe with two columns (working area) is gone. And if I use df.groupby('order number',)['time'].sum() I have the same problem. Please take a look at my print(df2) this is how it has to look like

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me, what you want to achieve? `'11xa'` has the working areas `'LLA'` and `'LLE'`. So either you ignore it (first code snippet) or you take into account (second code snippet).

Comment: again please run my code. The order number is 11xa. There are three tasks that correspond to that order number. The task LLA, LLE and LLS. I sum up all times which corresponds to this order, that is 20 and choose that working field with the highest time value. Therefore the working field is LLS because of the 13 minutes in the example. Especially I need to keep the rest of the data. Please run the demo code to see what I mean.

Comment: Updated and corrected the solution. Probably there are smarter solutions, but it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
rawData = {
    'order number': ['11xa', '11xa', '11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working area': ['LLA', 'LLE', 'LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': ['1', '6', '13', '35', '24']
}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
dataframe['time'] = dataframe['time'].astype(int)
dataframe.groupby(['order number']).sum().reset_index()
```

output

```
order number    time
0     11xa     20
1     21xb     35
2     31xc     24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , you can use `agg` to do this : (nb : small changes in the column names) :

```
rawData = {
    'order_number': ['11xa', '11xa', '11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working_area': ['LLA', 'LLE', 'LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': ['1', '6', '13', '35', '24']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(int)  
df = df.sort_values(['time'], ascending=True)

df = df.groupby(['order_number'], as_index=False).agg(dict(working_area='last', time='sum'))
```

Output :

```
   order_number  time working_area
0         11xa    20          LLS
1         21xb    35          MLA
2         31xc    24          MLE
```